# Tkinter cannot find filedialog?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm having some issues using tkinter. To start, I'm using Python 2, and I've seen people on SO use a mixture of `import tkinter` and `import Tkinter`; only the latter works for me, although there is another module names `_tkinter`. Which am I supposed to use here?

The real issue is that tkinter cannot find `filedialog`. I'm trying to do `path = Tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` but I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filedialog'`. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2's tkinter and Python 3's tkinter libraries have some differences.

Python **2**:

```
import Tkinter
```

Python **3**:

```
import tkinter
```

---

Python **2**:

```
import tkFileDialog # ( `as filedialog` )  to import the filedialog module
```

Python **3**:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

---

You have to use the Python 2 code samples. Every method call to tkinter should be the same in both Python versions. However you have to import different modules. For any further questions just search the wiki for **your** Python version (Python 2) or feel free to ask a new question here on Stack Overflow.